# firebase hosted website not updating after pushing to github

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

Why am I not seeing any changes to my website hosted with firebase hosting after I push to github? I have merged the code with master and it is able to build and deploy on github. In my actions, I see it say Deploy to Firebase Hosting with a green check mark so I am confused why its not updating the website. Here is a screenshot of my build_and_deploy action:

[image]

I have tried clearing cache and opening the browser on incognito mode but it still does not show the changes.